# Getting the exception in h2o when creating the context

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I get below exception in my code when I try to create a h2o contetx by Spark 1.6.3

```
17/11/06 12:01:39 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[H2O Launcher thread,5,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.DateTime.now()Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;
        at water.util.Timer.nowAsLogString(Timer.java:38)
        at water.util.Log.header(Log.java:163)
        at water.util.Log.write0(Log.java:131)
        at water.util.Log.write0(Log.java:124)
        at water.util.Log.write(Log.java:109)
        at water.util.Log.log(Log.java:86)
        at water.util.Log.info(Log.java:72)
        at water.H2OSecurityManager.<init>(H2OSecurityManager.java:57)
        at water.H2OSecurityManager.instance(H2OSecurityManager.java:79)
        at water.H2ONode.<init>(H2ONode.java:127)
```

EDIT: I have attached the POM file, it is a long file but it shows the dependency. I think there shoud be something wrong with my dependencies.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>au.com.vroc.mdm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mdm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.0</gson.version>
        <java.home>${env.JAVA_HOME}</java.home>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/h2o-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2o-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0.7</version>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/h2o-algos -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2o-algos</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0.7</version>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/h2o-genmodel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2o-genmodel</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0.7</version>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/sparkling-water-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <!-- <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId> <artifactId>sparkling-water-core_2.10</artifactId> 
                <version>1.6.11</version> -->

            <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>sparkling-water-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudera.livy</groupId>
            <artifactId>livy-client-http</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudera.livy</groupId>
            <artifactId>livy-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId> <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId> 
            <scope>system</scope> <version>1.8</version> <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0-HBase-1.1</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-cdh5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera.repo</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
            <name>Cloudera Repositories</name>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Local repository</id>
            <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <!-- <version>3.0.0</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!--<id>assemble-all</id> -->
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Creating of model is simply done by livyclient as follow:

```
public RegressionMetric call(JobContext ctx) throws Exception {
    if (!checkInputValid()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Mandatory parameters are not set");
    } else {
        RegressionMetric metric = new RegressionMetric();
        Dataset<Row> sensordataDF = this.InitializeH2OModel(ctx);

        SQLContext hc = ctx.sqlctx();

        // Save the H2OContext so that we can extract the H2oFrames later
        H2OContext h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(ctx.sc().sc());
    //...       
}
}
```

In above the InitializeH2OModel(ctx) is a complex function which generate the spark frame for training the model. The prgram can run correctly till the line which starts the h2o context "H2OContext h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(ctx.sc().sc());"

The configuration parameter which I add to livy is as follow:

```
    LivyClient client = new LivyClientBuilder().setURI(new URI(livyUrl)).setConf("spark.executor.instances", "9")
            .setConf("spark.driver.memory", "20g")
            .setConf("spark.driver.cores", "5")
            .setConf("spark.executor.memory", "16g") // memory per executor
            .setConf("spark.executor.cores", "5")
            .setConf("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "7000")
            .setConf("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
            .setConf("spark.default.parallelism", "3000")
            .setConf("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .setConf("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=10000m -Xss5000m")
            .setConf("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=10000m -Xss5000m")
            .setConf("spark.shuffle.compress", "true")
            .setConf("spark.shuffle.spill.compress", "true")
            .setConf("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1g")
            .setConf("spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries", "6")
            .setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "7000")
            .setConf("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "5000")
            .setConf("spark.driver.extraClassPath",
                    "/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205-client.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205-server.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/phoenix/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.6.2.0-205.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.6.2.0-205.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.6.2.0-205")
            .setConf("spark.executor.extraClassPath",
                    "/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205-client.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205-server.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/phoenix/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.2.6.2.0-205.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.6.2.0-205.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.2.6.2.0-205")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.cluster.size", "-1")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.cloud.timeout", "60000")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.spreadrdd.retries", "-1")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.nthreads", "-1")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.disable.ga", "true")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.dummy.rdd.mul.factor", "10")
              .setConf("spark.ext.h2o.fail.on.unsupported.spark.param", "false")
            .setConf("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "64")
            .setConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g")
            .setConf("spark.network.timeout", "1000s")
            .setConf("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "600s")
            .build();
```

I am running above on HDP 2.6.2 in cluster mode with Spark 2.1.1.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Spark 2.1 or Spark 1.6 ? At the very start of the question you are referring to Spark 1.6 but bellow to Spark 2.1. I will assume it's 2.1.

Regarding your problem, you are mixing versions in your pom file. You specified dependency for H2O 3.14.0.7 however you are using Sparkling Water 2.1.1 which is based on H2O 3.10.4.2. Both versions require different versions of JODA library which is also reason why you see the error above.

The solution is to specify just sparkling water dependencies in you pom file. H2O are already bundled inside sparkling water and you are not supposed to specify them explicitly.

The dependencies you should put into your pom file are:

- `ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.11:2.1.16`
- `ai.h2o:sparkling-water-examples_2.11:2.1.16`
- `no.priv.garshol.duke:duke:1.2`

Also it is advised to use latest sparkling water versions, which in case for Spark 2.1.x is Sparkling Water 2.1.16.

We are working on this PR https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/pull/352 which will simplify this a little bit and instead of these 3 dependencies you could just specify one uber dependency as:

- `ai.h2o:sparkling-water-package_2.11:2.1.16`

Comment: Hi Thnaks for your response, I have fixed the dependencies I never get Joda exception anymore but I am getting kyro excpetion when I use kyro serilizer in my Spark application.._transform (hex.aggregator.AggregatorModel$AggregatorParameters)
aggregatorParameters (au.com.vroc.mdm.H2oModel)
        at com.cloudera.livy.shaded.kryo.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at com.cloudera.livy.shaded.kryo.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
   ..do u have any opinion how to resolve the kyro exception as well?